# How to Toggle Visibility of FAB with Another FAB

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This code makes the FAB to be pressed disappear:

```
val fab = findViewById(R.id.fab) as FloatingActionButton
    fab.setOnClickListener({ view ->
        findViewById(R.id.fab2)

        if(view.visibility == VISIBLE) {
            view.visibility = INVISIBLE
        }
        else view.visibility = VISIBLE
```

Comment: At one press that gonna disappear your view and never it appear again  by click on same fab view(which are already hidden). As per code interpretation ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findViewById(R.id.fab1).setOnClickListener {
    val fab2 = findViewById(R.id.fab2)

    fab2.visibility = if(fab2.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.INVISIBLE else View.VISIBLE
}
```

or

```
findViewById(R.id.fab1).setOnClickListener { view ->
    val fab2 = findViewById(R.id.fab2)

    fab2.visibility = if(fab2.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.INVISIBLE else View.VISIBLE
}
```

or

```
findViewById(R.id.fab1).setOnClickListener {
    findViewById(R.id.fab2).apply { 
        visibility = if(visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.INVISIBLE else View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying "fab2.visibility", but "visibility" would turn red. I guess taking out "view" was the answer to that. For future reference, why was that the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @BaldAndroid did you try Kotlin Android Extensions? If so, you need to add correct imports to your code. Check it out https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: I'm using Android Studio v3. Your code worked, I was just wondering why removing "view" made it work so I know when to include it and when not to.

Comment: @BaldAndroid updated the answer. We can type `view ->` as well.

Comment: Oh, OK. I see what the problem was now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
fab1=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab1);
fab2=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab2);
fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
public void onClick(View view){
if(fab2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
fab.setVisibility(View.GONE)or invisible
else
fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

}});
```